# In Select: Show value only if greater than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with two int columns and I try the following: in the `SELECT` statement for the table, I will if one of this values is 0 that the column will be empty.

I have tried with this SQL but then I got `0` and not `''`:

```
SELECT 
    Typ
    , Nummer
    , IIF(ATBPos > 0 , ATBPos, '') AS ATBPos
    , IIF(ATBStk > 0 , ATBStk, '') AS ATBStk
    , ID
FROM 
    Vorpapier
WHERE 
    FremdID = 1
    AND PosNummer = 1
```

Table `Vorpapier` looks like this:

```
Nummer (varchar) | ATBPos (int) | ATbStk (int) | Typ (varchar)
-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------
54542542542      | 0            | 0            | OHNE
45454            | 15           | 45           | ATB
```

And the result should look like this:

```
Nummer (varchar) | ATBPos (int) | ATbStk (int) | Typ (varchar)
-----------------+--------------+--------------+--------------
54542542542      |              |              | OHNE
45454            | 15           | 45           | ATB
```

Comment: what's your DB?

Comment: DB is: MS SQL 11.0

Comment: I wonder if there are negative integer values for ATBPos and/or ATbStk columns ?

Comment: It depands on the TYP, only if Tyo is ATB then this two Values are greater then 0 otherwiese they are 0

Comment: The problem, in case you are still wondering, is that your '' result is being casted to int because the first result data type is int. Casting an empty string to int results as 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

`iif( ATBPos = 0, null, ATBPos ) as ATBPos`

and

`iif( ATBStk = 0, null, ATBStk ) as ATBStk`

Comment: I got a error: SQL (102) Incorrect syntax near "ATBPos". Think this is becuase in int colume can not be Null

Comment: @Zam89 please have a look at [little demo](https://rextester.com/APIKW18197) we do not changing the structure of the table, but just the displaying style.

Comment: You are right, I have a typing error in my SQL, sorry for that

Comment: @Zam89 not important :)

Answer (score 3):

you can cast to varchar.

```
SELECT 
    Typ
    , Nummer
    , IIF(ATBPos > 0 , cast(ATBPos as varchar), '') AS ATBPos
    , IIF(ATBStk > 0 , cast(ATBStk as varchar), '') AS ATBStk
    , ID
FROM 
    Vorpapier
WHERE 
    FremdID = 1
    AND PosNummer = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, an expression returns a specific type.  In this case, the type is a number, and `''` is not a number.  So, it is converted to one, which is where the `0` comes from.

The solution is to use compatible types.  I recommend using a `case` expression (`case` is part of standard SQL).  It looks like:

```
SELECT Typ, Nummer,
       (CASE WHEN ATBPos > 0 THEN ATBPos END) AS ATBPos,
       (CASE WHEN ATBStk > 0 THEN ATBStk END) AS ATBStk, ID
FROM Vorpapier
WHERE FremdID = 1 AND
      PosNummer = 1;
```

Alternatively, if you really want a blank string rather than `NULL`, then use type conversion:

```
SELECT Typ, Nummer,
       (CASE WHEN ATBPos > 0 THEN CAST(ATBPos as VARCHAR(255)) ELSE '' END) AS ATBPos,
       (CASE WHEN ATBStk > 0 THEN CAST(ATBStk as VARCHAR(255)) ELSE '' END) AS ATBStk, ID
FROM Vorpapier
WHERE FremdID = 1 AND
      PosNummer = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
SELECT 
    Typ
    , Nummer
    , (CASE WHEN ATBPos > 0 then  ATBPos ELSE '' END)  as ATBPos 
    , (CASE WHEN ATBStk > 0 then  ATBStk ELSE '' END)  as ATBStk 
    , ID
FROM 
    Vorpapier
WHERE 
    FremdID = 1
    AND PosNummer = 1
```

OR you should change IIF to if in your sql query. Try also :-

```
SELECT 
    Typ
    , Nummer
    , IF(ATBPos > 0 , ATBPos, '') AS ATBPos
    , IF(ATBStk > 0 , ATBStk, '') AS ATBStk
    , ID
FROM 
    Vorpapier
WHERE 
    FremdID = 1
    AND PosNummer = 1
```